# Oracle SQL: Return previous n-rows order by date after condition

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I need to return the previous 3 rows after condition of a set of data ordered by date. See bellow the query with a few data:

> select invoice, cli_id, sale_date,processed
>   from sales
>   where cli_id = '490727'
>   order by sale_date

- INVOICE  CLI_ID  SALE_DATE   PROCESSED
- 7995781  490727  04/07/2018 15:30:36 W
- 7995782  490727  04/07/2018 15:30:39 Q
- 7995783  490727  04/07/2018 15:30:41 Q
- 7995784  490727  04/07/2018 15:30:43 Q
- 7995792  490727  04/07/2018 15:31:01 W  ====>
- 7995793  490727  04/07/2018 15:31:03 Q
- 7995794  490727  04/07/2018 15:31:06 Q
- 7995795  490727  04/07/2018 15:31:08 Q

I need to return previous 3 rows of before of certain condition ==> processed='W'
Ex: want to know the 3 previous rows of PROCESSED = 'W' where invoice is 7995792. it will return:
7995793, 7995794 and 7995795

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 12C, you can use:

```
select s.*
from sales s
where s.sale_date < (select s2.sale_date
                     from sales s2
                     where s2.cli_id = s.cli_id and s2.processed = 'W'
                    ) and
      s.cli_id = 490727
order by s.sale_date desc
fetch first 3 rows only;
```

In earlier versions, you need a subquery:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*
      from sales s
      where s.sale_date < (select s2.sale_date
                           from sales s2
                           where s2.cli_id = s.cli_id and s2.processed = 'W'
                          ) and
            s.cli_id = 490727
      order by s.sale_date desc
     ) s
where rownum <= 3;
```